# Exported shapefile to SVG - but can't see in browser window

Tags: svg, postgis

I've exported a shapefile from PostGIS to SVG using ST_AsSVG. I chose to use relative coordinates for the export. The result of the export is here:

http://pastebin.com/rmB89Pyw

When I put this into a very simple HTML page with an SVG path element, I don't see any of the path. I"m guessing it's something to do with the viewBox/scaling/transform - but I'm not sure where to start, this is my first foray into this area.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way I found to embed your shape:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="800"
     height="600"
     style="border: 1px solid red">
  <path
     transform="translate(400,300) scale(.01, .01) translate(-323712.401, 4848647.35)"
     d="... YOUR PATH ..." />
</svg>

</body>
</html>
```

What I did is put a "transform" attribute to (from right to left):

- translate the first point of you path to 0,0
- scale the path (by 0.01), I tried a few scales
- translate the 0,0 (you first point) to the middle of the svg image (400, 300)

I think you can adapt this to do exactly what you want (or even make a script to extract the bounding box informations etc).